# make the thumbnail slider from vertical to horizontal

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this [jquery](http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumbnail-slider-demo-3) slider in my app.

If you see the demo there, the thumbnail is on right side of the image, is it possible to make it below the main image and in horizontal mode?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes here is the similar slider in horizontal version
http://www.menucool.com/slider/flickr-like-slideshow